# Azure ServiceBus SubscriptionClient.EndReceive() returns null

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I call BeginReceive() on a SubscriptionClient like this:

```
client.BeginReceive(new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0), new AsyncCallback(DownloadResults), null);
```

And in the DownloadResults() callback I call client.EndReceive() [client is a static member of the class]

```
static public void DownloadResults(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Get the message from the service bus.
    msg = client.EndReceive(ar);
    if (msg == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Sometimes client.EndReceive() returns `null`. It's not very clear to me by looking at the MSDN page for SubscriptionClient.EndReceive() as to exactly when EndReceive() returns `null`. Is it because the timelimit I specified in BeginReceive() was exceeded? Or is it because there was an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if the time limit is exceeded, the callback is called. When we try to retrieve the message by calling `SubscriptionClient.EndReceive()`, `null` will be returned.

The default timeout value is one minute, and there is no way to set an infinite timeout. If you want an infinite timeout, you can call `SubscriptionClient.BeginReceive()` again if the message is `null`.

For example:

```
static public void DownloadResults(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Get the message from the service bus.
    msg = client.EndReceive(ar);
    if (msg == null)
    {
        // Start waiting for the message again.
        client.BeginReceive(new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0), new AsyncCallback(DownloadResults), null);
        return;
    }
}
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b14587ce-3fc7-4b56-8a35-4f2c6babce26/servicebus-subscriptionclientendreceive-returns-null

Answer (score 0):

The contract for Receive states that ServiceBus will not throw an Exception. When Receive/BeginReceive/ReceiveAsync times out, the call will do whatever it needs to do to return a value (such as execute your callback) and you will get back a null in a timeout situation.